# PHP Regex preg_match Email Validation

Tags: php, regex

```
$email = 'john@business.com';
if(preg_match(\w+(@business.com)\z), $email){code goes here}
```

I'm trying to execute code in the "code goes here" section of this condition when $email contains an email address that ends in exactly `@business.com`.

I feel like I'm perhaps misunderstanding how `preg_match` works, but I can't find any information as to why the if statement is evaluating as false.

There are many, many examples and other people having similar problems, but the solution to their problems doesn't seem to highlight any issues with my code.

I was working off this example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? `preg_match(\w+(@business.com)\z),` has atleast two issues. 1. no quotes around regex, 2. no delimiters.

Comment: @chris85 as it seems that there's no need to use regex over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `regex` you can simply use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function of PHP  like as

```
if(strstr('xyz@business.com',"@") == "@business.com"){
  // code goes here
}
```

or for using regex you can simply use Positive Lookbehind like as

```
if(preg_match('~(?<=\w)(@business.com)~',$string)!==false){
    // code goes here
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/448220)